# Start process in emacs lisp that continues after lisp program ends

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I start off a process in emacs lisp that will continue running after the emacs lisp program ends? I'm writing a utility script that should start an interactive GUI program and exit.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I guess I'm looking for the emacs lisp equivalent of this C++ code.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    pid_t p = fork();
    if (p == 0) {
        // child process
        execl("process_to_run", "process_to_run", nullptr);
    } else {
        // stuff for parent to do
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not answer your question entirely, but the following package makes something very similar to what you want: https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/openwith/overview

It basically opens a file with an external program (such as okular, gimp...) and

> "wraps commands in nohup on Unix so launched processes will not exit if Emacs exits."

I don't know it's implementation details, but you could try to read their code. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there's no method of preventing Emacs from terminating its sub-processes upon exit, whether synchronous, asynchronous, or executed via `shell-command`. If you use any of the Emacs primitives for executing a sub-process (i.e., `start-process` or `call-process` and their variants) and attempt to exit Emacs before the processes finish, Emacs will invariably either prompt you to kill them or kill them automatically if you've set `process-query-on-exit-flag` to `nil` for each of said processes. Attempting to use some sort of shell-based hackery involving `shell-command` and `bash` built-ins like `bg`, `disown`, `setsid`, etc. is pointless because `shell-command` ultimately invokes the aforementioned `start-process` or `call-process` primitives.

As an aside, I think ELisp is an exceedingly poor choice for scripting (and if your script isn't written entirely in ELisp then I fail to comprehend why you need to execute your sub-processes from within Emacs itself). One possibility that you might consider is starting Emacs as a daemon (which automatically detaches Emacs from the controlling terminal and initiates a server process that `emacsclient` can communicate with) and using `emacsclient -e` to issue commands to it. I don't know if that's applicable, but it may be of use.

You haven't really provided any detail about your script, so it's difficult to offer any further concrete advice at this point. I'll say this: the sane thing to do is simply to write the part of the script that needs to operate independent of Emacs in `bash` and use its job control mechanisms (i.e., run background process and `disown` it, etc.), or some other scripting language, such as Perl (which I believe explicitly has its own `fork()` function).